# Is my solution on Feynman Kac question correct?

Tags: probability, solution-verification, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Question: Consider the solution $X$ of the SDE

$$
d X_{t}=\left(\theta-X_{t}\right) d t+\sigma \sqrt{X_{t}\left(1-X_{t}\right)} d W_{t}
$$

for parameters $\sigma>0$ and $\theta \in(0,1)$. (It is known that a unique solution exists for every initial value $0 \leq x \leq 1$ and that the solution is an element of $[0,1]$ for all $t$.) Define for parameters $\rho_{0}, \rho_{1}>0$ the function

$$
F(t, x)=E_{x}\left(\exp \left(-\int_{0}^{T-t} \rho_{0}+\rho_{1} X_{s} d s\right)\right), \quad(t, x) \in[0, T] \times[0,1]
$$

Use the Feynman Kac formula to derive a terminal value problem for $F$.

---

---

---

### This is what I've tried:

To derive a terminal value problem for the function $F(t, x)$ using the Feynman-Kac formula, we first consider the associated backward Kolmogorov equation. The Feynman-Kac formula relates the solution of a partial differential equation to the solution of a stochastic differential equation.

Let's denote the backward Kolmogorov operator as $\mathcal{A}$. In this case, it is given by:

$$
\mathcal{A} u(t, x) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + (\theta - x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x(1 - x) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$

We aim to solve the backward Kolmogorov equation:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + (\theta - x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x(1 - x) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0
$$

with the terminal condition:

$$
u(T, x) = \exp\left(-\int_{0}^{T} \rho_{0} + \rho_{1} X_s ds\right)
$$

Now, we can rewrite the function $F(t, x)$ in terms of the solution of the backward Kolmogorov equation $u(t, x)$ using the Feynman-Kac formula:

$$
F(t, x) = \mathbb{E}_x\left[\exp\left(-\int_{t}^{T} \rho_{0} + \rho_{1} X_s ds\right)\right] = u(t, x)
$$

Therefore, the function $F(t, x)$ is equivalent to the solution of the backward Kolmogorov equation $u(t, x)$.

To summarize, the terminal value problem for $F(t, x)$ using the Feynman-Kac formula is given by:

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + (\theta - x) \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x(1 - x) \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} = 0
$$

with the terminal condition:

$$
u(T, x) = \exp\left(-\int_{0}^{T} \rho_{0} + \rho_{1} X_s ds\right)
$$

where $X_s$ follows the stochastic differential equation:

$$
d X_{s} = (\theta - X_s) ds + \sigma \sqrt{X_s(1 - X_s)} d W_s
$$

with $0 \leq s \leq T$ and $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Very strange. A terminal or initial condition to a PDE is usually a function $u(t,x)$ evaluated at $t=T$ resp. $t=0\,.$ Your "terminal condition" is a random variable. Also if $\rho_0,\rho_1$ are parameters of the solution they should show up in the PDE. For a systematic introduction to Feynman-Kac, see Karatzas & Shreve, *Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus.*